# Velocity change of air down a cone?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, air, flow, bernoulli-equation

Does the velocity of fluids (specifically gasses) change when traveling down a cone from the wide opening to the narrow opening? If so, is there an equation used to calculate the acceleration or predict the outcome velocity?

Comment: Something like [Bernoulli's equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pressure change across the cone is small (e.g., no significant density changes for the flowing gas), use the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation).  With constant density, this simplifies to $A_1 
\cdot v_1 = A_2 \cdot v_2$, where $A$ is the cross sectional area of the flow stream and $v$ is the velocity of the flow stream.  If you additionally need the acceleration, you have $v_1, \quad v_2$, and change in length.  The kinematic equation $v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2a\Delta x$ will allow you to calculate acceleration from your other variables.

Comment: User36790 - what editing tool are you using?  Is that tool available online for Google chrome operating on Windows 7, or do I need to edit my work offline and import it onto this web page?